# Access content on canvas with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I have very little experience with canvas but I am attempting to access some code written by someone else. I am used to working with the DOM in HTML so I am finding the canvas very unusual.

Their code modifies the canvas and adds two text values. I need to access these two values in my javascript code and read them.

Is this possible? Searching in Google is giving so few answers that I am worried it is not.

Edit: Before anyone asks, the only part I have understood so far is the following:

```
$("#canvas")[0].getContext('2d');
```

I am not sure where to go from here. Many thanks

Comment: In the code that is drawing to the canvas, just peek at it to figure out which variables hold the text data. And if you want to read them from canvas output, then you can extract the pixel, process the pixel data and then use some library to extract texts (which may not be trivial).

Comment: You have not given us enough clues to help you. However, in general, text is written on canvas using the `context.fillText` command. Look for `fillText` in their code and the first argument will be the text values you are seeking.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery [get()](http://api.jquery.com/get/) method as follows :

```
var canvas = $("#canvas").get(0);
var twoDContext = canvas.getContext('2d');
```

Comment: I wrote that I am at this point in my question. How do I access specific text values after retrieving twoDContext?

Comment: I don't think this is possible, you can access only limited things such as the getImageData() method which returns an ImageData object that copies the pixel data for the specified rectangle on a canvas. But not specific text..

Comment: @James: Grabbing a reference to the `context` will not help very much. The context does not store information about what it draws on the canvas so you can't ask it for your 2 text values. Fetching the pixel information is not useful because optical character recognition is a very difficult process and is often ineffective. ;-//

Comment: @markE So it's basically impossible to gather the information? After seeing this was impossible, I changed strategy and am trying to intercept the values before they are written on the canvas. I have got it working but I am still interested in this concept as I have worked so little with the canvas. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: @James, Not impossible, just difficult & unreliable (probably not worth the effort). It would involve character recognition software

Comment: Note: It's not impossible (just very hard). Canvas just just a pixel array visualized, so as people said you could do OCR-ing. ( stick with the intercept plan though)